# Ethernet valdiation

Tags: validation, ethernet

To make it simple, lets assume my company makes cables. I need an easy tool to validate that our cables fully support 100Mb Ethernet connection without any package lost. Is there a program / tool which can perform a full speed test of like an hour and monitor the lost packages as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might have some luck with [iPerf](https://iperf.fr/). It can stress-test a network connection and measure packet loss. You'd put an iPerf server at one end of the cable, and run the client on a machine at the other end.

Comment: Can the iPerf server run on something very easy like a Raspberry pi?

Comment: @mikla90, yes, it can.

Answer (score -1):

To validate a twisted-pair cable for Cat-5e, Cat-6 or Cat-6A you need a professional cable tester (starts at 1000€ or so). Everything else is just try and error. You cannot seriously certify a cable using commodity hardware and some software.

Comment: The point is, we need data to show. Our "cables" will never pass a validation test from a cable tester because of noise and impedence variation. This is why I want to test them via software, to demonstrate the actual reliability of the products.

Comment: You can't replace missing hardware with software. Simply not possible. I'm voting to close because it's not programming related.

Comment: What I want is just to create a program that can send and monitor packages over network. Let's not get involed on the why I want to do that.

Comment: You can open a UDP socket and run data at full speed across. Where's the problem?

Comment: My apologies, as I said above I need to be able to monitor that there are no packet loss. So UDP is not ideal.

Comment: Why not? If you send numbered datagrams and one isn't received it's been lost.

Comment: So you mean like counting the number of sent packages vs the number of received packages? I'm quite a newby on this topic.

Comment: You send a dummy payload with a unique number in each datagram and the receiver checks for consecutive numbers and counts misses.

Comment: That could work! Can I just set it to send as many packets as possible while counting on the receiver, and then comparing the output number?

Comment: Basically, yes. You need to make sure that the sender's bandwidth doesn't exceed the receiver's bandwidth (e.g. 1000 vs 100 Mbit/s across a switch), then you should be fine.

Comment: Is there a way to limit the amount of packages per second (basically limit the bandwidth)?